# Can't access Amazon S3 files through Cloudfront with SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a origin in Cloudfront: `mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path`
And a behavior that use this origin to serve `*.jpg`.

I also have a default Behavior serving a static web site from another origin (another bucket).
Both behaviours is set to `HTTP and HTTPS`.
SSL works fine for the website.

However, when i try to browse a image directly only **http** works.

http://www.example.com/image.jpg does work

But the same URL with **https** just render the website (as if the behaviour was not triggered).

Do I need to configure something on the S3 side?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than "doesn't work" about what you see when the request fails.

Comment: As i described, the request with https does not fails, it renders the website as i would have browsed www.example.com. Instead of serving the image in the way it does if i go to the same URL with http.

Thats why i'm thinking the cloudfront behaviour is not triggering.